# WatchOS 2 calibrate Pedometer

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, core-motion, calibration, watchos-2

I want to build a running application where you can also run only with your Apple Watch (and leave your phone at home).

this site (http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-calibrate-the-apple-watch-for-improved-accuracy/) states that

> Calibration is performed automatically whenever you use the Apple Watch's Outdoor Walk or Outdoor Run features in the Workout app. So from your Apple Watch, tap the Digital Crown, select the Workout app and choose Outdoor Walk or Outdoor Run.

Does this also work if I create a WorkoutSession directly in my App with WatchOS 2 or does the user have to start the Apple Workout App to calibrate the Pedometer accordingly?
So I would like to tell the user that he has to run his first run with the phone (to calibrate the watch) and then he can run without it. The question is, if the calibration **ONLY** works with the Apple Watch Workout App or also with a WorkoutSession in a third party App.